# What is the best way to coordinate Volley requests

Tags: android, oop, android-volley

I'm trying to use Volley to execute multiple HTTP request where each one of them relies on the result of the previous one, what is the best option as a design?

1-Firing the next request in the `onResponse` callback of the previous request?

2-Writing some coordinator class that have callbacks that get called in the `onResponse` method of a request and fires the next request

skeleton code for the second option

```
coodrinator = new Coordinator();
    JsonObjectRequest firstRequest = new JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,firstURL),new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //handle the responsee
            coordinator.onFirstRequestRecieved();
        }
    },
    errorListener);


    private void doSecondRequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest secondRequest = new JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,secondURL),new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //handle the responsee
                coordinator.onSecondRequestRecieved();
            }
        },
                errorListener);
    }

    private class Coordinator{
        public void onFirstReequestRecieved(){
            doSecondRequest();
        }
        public void onSecondRequestRecieved(){
            //do Something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If first request response parameters are needed for making second request and so on then you can go for synchronous way. That can be achieved by making second request in onResponse on First request can there is no good or bad practise for it.

The thing is volley is asynchronous and request what is added in the queue execute without depending on other request and we are going to make it synchronous request and it can be achieved by many ways seeing your requirement.